# Php - Choosing a function at runtime

Tags: php, function

I do not know what this is called.

I want to do this

```
// Elsewhere
function A($arg){
    echo "Hi" . $arg;
}
function B($arg){
    echo "Bye" . $arg;
}

for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
    $FunctionUse = $i==0 ? A : B;
    $FunctionUse("Rewind");
}
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).

Also, make sure you check this link [Variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

Also, your code will work too, if you change the `A` and `B` to be strings, like this:

```
$FunctionUse = $i==0 ? 'A' : 'B';
```

Comment: Marked as answer for $FunctionUse = $i==0 ? 'A' : 'B';

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short and simple solution:

```
$a = function ($arg){
  echo "Hi" . $arg;
}

$b = function ($arg){
    echo "Bye" . $arg;
}

for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
  $FunctionUse = $i==0 ? $a : $b;
  $FunctionUse("Rewind");
}
```

Be aware that the function now has variable scope. You might need to to define it as global inside a function or class:

```
global $a, $b;
```

But to solve the case you present, it's easier to use an if statement.

Answer (score -1):

use call_user_func:

```
// Elsewhere
function A($arg){
    echo "Hi" . $arg;
}
function B($arg){
    echo "Bye" . $arg;
}

for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
    $FunctionUse = $i==0 ? 'A' : 'B';
    call_user_func($FunctionUse, "Rewind");
}
```